# Aptana + GVIM => integrating vi editor like functionality in Aptana

Tags: eclipse, ruby-on-rails-3, vim, aptana

I recently started coding Rails app. After trying out a few IDE's, I settled for Aptana (running on Ubuntu 11.04).

It's a neat IDE. However, I really miss some of the gvim functionality and I was wondering if Aptana has a plugin to enable vi-like behavior of command and insert-mode.

Comment: On a side note. If you then decide to go back to Vim. Try out the Janus package: http://github.com/carlhuda/janus It'll help you get started on your development needs, since it already comes with pre-installed Vim plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this plugin called [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) that I used a while back. You might find it very helpful as well.

Back in the day, I also looked at one called [viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/). This one isn't free though.

I stuck with Vrapper + Aptana. Before switching back to MacVim, after a few months :-D. Just felt more natural and lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Aptana Studio allows you to create a console tab.  You can run native vim inside the console tab inside Aptana.  Create a new console tab for each file, type vim then drag the file you want to edit onto your tab.  Then you dont have to switch context so many times and you still get all the other features of the IDE in the same app.